# Contact form 7 Errores Content Security Policy

Tags: php, html, wordpress, formularios

Me han aparecido los siguientes errores en la consola al instalar contact form 7.

```html
Content Security Policy: Ignorando "'unsafe-inline'" dentro de script-src: se ha especificado "strict-dynamic"
Content Security Policy: Ignorando "https:" dentro de script-src: se ha especificado "strict-dynamic"
Content Security Policy: Ignorando "http:" dentro de script-src: se ha especificado "strict-dynamic"
Content Security Policy: Ignorando "https://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com" dentro de script-src: se ha especificado "strict-dynamic"
Content Security Policy: Ignorando "wss://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com" dentro de script-src: se ha especificado "strict-dynamic"
Content Security Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en https://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js (script-src).
Ha fallado la carga del <script> con origen "https://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js".
```

En este articulo explican un poco qué es, pero no se bien como solucionarlo del todo.
https://www.elarraydejota.com/implementando-content-security-policy-en-el-blog-wordpress/

Pueden decirme algo que pueda hacer para superar estos errores??